# Maximize / Resize to Display Resolution a Windows-10 C# UWP App?

Tags: c#, uwp, resize, display, maximize

In the below version of App.xaml.cs, written using Visual Studio 2019, associated with my Windows C# UWP solution / project called Example_Application, class App's constructor successfully resizes the blue app window that appears when starting the app. My question: Assuming a resolution scale of 1, just to make things easier, how do I change 1920 and 1080 to the two numbers comprising my Windows-10 display resolution?

```
namespace Example_Application
{
    sealed partial class App : Windows.UI.Xaml.Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Windows.Foundation.Size(1920, 1080);
            Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
        }

        protected override void OnLaunched(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame rootFrame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
}
```

Things I've tried:

1. Changing "PreferredLaunchViewSize" to "Maximized" does not maximize my blue window on my monitor. Changing "PreferredLaunchViewSize" to "FullScreen" does make my application take up the full screen, but this is not what I want because I want to be able to see my application title bar and my Windows-10 taskbar.
2. I can write `Windows.Foundation.Rect visibleBounds = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;` only at the very end of OnLaunched, and bounds' Width and Height properties return present application width and height, not Windows-10 display resolution.
3. I can write `uint screenWidthInRawPixels = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ScreenWidthInRawPixels;` only at the very end of OnLaunched, and screenWidthInRawPixels is the present application width, not Windows-10 display width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I choose to maximize my UWP App (written in C#) in my workspace, that area of my screen above my Windows taskbar. I would like to provide minimal instructions for creating a maximized app that you know is working.

I created a new default Blank App (Universal Windows) using C# in Visual Studio Community 2019, called "Draw Bounding Boxes". I included spaces here so that I could access "Draw Bounding Boxes" with spaces from my Start Menu.

I replaced the contents of "App.xaml.cs" with the following code block.

```
namespace Draw_Bounding_Boxes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Windows.UI.Xaml.Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Resize app.
            uint screenWidthInRawPixels = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ScreenWidthInRawPixels;
            uint screenHeightInRawPixels = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ScreenHeightInRawPixels;
            double rawPixelsPerViewPixel = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
            double screenWidthInViewPixels = System.Convert.ToDouble(screenWidthInRawPixels) / rawPixelsPerViewPixel;
            double screenHeightInViewPixels = System.Convert.ToDouble(screenHeightInRawPixels) / rawPixelsPerViewPixel;

            // If offsetToScreenWidthInViewPixels is less than 15,
            // on first load app will be of default size, and on second load app will be full screen.
            // A loaded image will have height equal to full screen height minus app title bar height minus app toolbar height minus 5 view pixels of padding.
            // Part of a loaded image with aspect ratio less than one will be behind Windows taskbar.
            // This is all very complicated and undesirable.
            // If offsetToScreenHeightInViewPixels is less than 40,
            // on first load app will be of default size, and on second load app will be full screen.
            // A loaded image will have height equal to full screen height minus app title bar height minus app toolbar height minus 5 view pixels of padding.
            // Part of a loaded image with aspect ratio less than one will be behind Windows taskbar.
            // This is all very complicated and undesirable.
            // If offsetToScreenWidthInViewPixels is greater than or equal to 15 and offsetToScreenHeightInViewPixels is greater than or equal to 40,
            // on first load app will be of PreferredLaunchViewSize, and a loaded image with aspect ratio less than one will have height exactly equal to height of app minus app title bar height minus app toolbar height.
            // If PreferredLaunchViewSize.Height is only screenHeightInViewPixels - offsetToScreenHeightInViewPixels,
            // part of app and a loaded image with aspect ratio less than one will be behind taskbar.
            // If taskbarHeight is taken off of screenHeightInViewPixels - offsetToScreenHeightInViewPixels,
            // bottom of app and coincident bottom of loaded image will be slightly above taskbar.
            // I consider this ideal.
            double offsetToScreenWidthInViewPixels = 15;
            double offsetToScreenHeightInViewPixels = 40;
            double taskbarHeight = 40;
            Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Windows.Foundation.Size(screenWidthInViewPixels - offsetToScreenWidthInViewPixels, screenHeightInViewPixels - offsetToScreenHeightInViewPixels - taskbarHeight);
            Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;

            // Set the app window to a new Frame.
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame rootFrame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

            // Navigate the frame to the initial default page.
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);

            // Attempts to activate the application window by bringing it to the foreground and setting the input focus to it.
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Activate();

        } // protected override void OnLaunched
    } // sealed partial class App
} // namespace Draw_Bounding_Boxes
```

I added property `x:Name="page"` to the `<Page>` tag in "MainPage.xaml".

I removed the `<Grid> </Grid>` environment from MainPage.xaml.

I replaced the contents of "MainPage.xaml.cs" with the following code block.

```
// Create namespace Draw_Bounding_Boxes to contain all classes associated with our app.
namespace Draw_Bounding_Boxes
{
    // Create class MainPage that inherits fields and methods from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page and
    // is used to declare and define user-interface elements and functionality.
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        // Create constructor public MainPage.
        public MainPage()
        {
            // Necessary to instantiate this Page, add a stackPanel to this Page, et cetera.
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Find width of app in view pixels and height between bottom of app and bottom of title bar in view pixels.
            double widthOfAppInViewPixels = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize.Width;
            double heightBetweenBottomOfAppAndBottomOfTitleBarInViewPixels = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize.Height;

            // Create a stackPanel.
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel stackPanel = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel();

            // Create a toolbar with width equal to the width of the app, height equal to 50 view pixels, and background color of light blue that has one row and four columns.
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid toolbar = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid();
            toolbar.Width = widthOfAppInViewPixels;
            toolbar.Height = 50;
            toolbar.Background = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.AliceBlue);
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RowDefinition row = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RowDefinition();
            toolbar.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ColumnDefinition column = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ColumnDefinition();
            column.Width = new Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength(widthOfAppInViewPixels);
            toolbar.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);

            stackPanel.Children.Add(toolbar);

            page.Content = stackPanel;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the screen resolution in UWP apps, you could try to use [DisplayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.screenheightinrawpixels#Windows_Graphics_Display_DisplayInformation_ScreenHeightInRawPixels) and [DisplayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.screenwidthinrawpixels).

Like the following code:

```
  protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
           ........
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        //screen resolution
        string heightsize = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ScreenHeightInRawPixels.ToString();
        string widthsize = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ScreenWidthInRawPixels.ToString();
        Size mysize = new Size(Convert.ToDouble(widthsize), Convert.ToDouble(heightsize));


        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = mysize;
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
    }
```

My resolution is 1920*1080. In my test, it could get my screen resolution correctly as 1920*1080.

Comment: Roy, thank you for your suggestion. I believe I mentioned trying this in the third item under “Things I’ve tried”. While perhaps these definitions do retrieve display resolution numbers, I believe these definitions are only implementable after MainPage is assigned to the app window, which does not allow for resizing the app window. In case I haven’t implemented your suggestion in the right place, would you recommend an insertion point? If you are willing, would you try your suggestion with a HelloWorld-type app and let me know if you get your window to resize to fill your screen?

Comment: @TomLever, I edited my answer. I'm using these codes at the end of the OnLaunched event. And yes, it's a simple blank app.  But please note, the `PreferredLaunchViewSize` will work when the second time that you launch the app.  Is it acceptable for you?

Comment: Roy, you got me back on track. Your solution worked for me, after I built my solution and started in twice. Thanks. Any idea why it takes two starts?

Comment: @TomLever The code for `PreferredLaunchViewSize ` and `PreferredLaunchViewSize` mode could work when the first time the app is launched in the app's Construction method. The reason for this behavior is that when we are calling `DisplayInformation` Class to get the screen resolution, we need to make sure the ApplicationView(the single instance for the current thread's CoreApplicationView) is activated. That means this `DisplayInformation` Class must be called after `Window.Current.Activate()`.

Comment: @TomLever So we could only get the correct resolution at the end of OnLaunched method and set it to the preferred size after the window is shown. Then it will work for the second time because the preferred size is set this time.